# Change dropdown options if radio button selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 radio buttons selected, if the user chooses one of them I am wanting all but 2 options to disappear from a dropdown list further down the page, can anyone help please? If someone selects the third option (id="notify_type3") then I only want the dropdown to show an initial "select" (`<option value="">Please select</option>`) and one other option (for example, `<option value="4">Option 4</option>`), if the other 2 radio buttons are selected then it needs to show the whole list.

```
Staff member
<input type="radio" name="notify_type" id="notify_type1" value="new member of staff">
Editorial Freelance
<input type="radio" name="notify_type" id="notify_type2" value="new freelance user">
Contractor/Consultant
<input type="radio" name="notify_type" id="notify_type3" value="new contractor user">

<select class="dropdown" name="starter_company" id="starter_company">
<option value="">Please select</option>
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="2">Option 2</option>
<option value="3">Option 3</option>
<option value="4">Option 4</option>
<option value="5">Option 5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably hide the drop down menu entirely until the user selects an option, and then display it. But I would do something like this, that way, if they change the radio button back your options will re-appear.

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/mvzpj6hr/)

```
$("input[type='radio'][name='notify_type']").change(function(){

    var selected = $("input[type='radio'][name='notify_type']:checked").val();

    if(selected == "new contractor user") var opts = [
        {name:"Please Select", val:""},
        {name:"Option 4", val:"4"}
    ];

    else var opts = [
        {name:"Please Select", val:""},
        {name:"Option 1", val:"1"},
        {name:"Option 2", val:"2"},
        {name:"Option 3", val:"3"},
        {name:"Option 4", val:"4"}
    ];

    $("#starter_company").empty();

    $.each(opts, function(k,v){

        $("#starter_company").append("<option value='"+v.val+"'>"+v.name+"</option>");

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this

```
$("#notify_type1").click(function(){
   $('.selDiv option[value="SEL1"]') .remove() 
})


// SEL1 will be value you desired to remove after clicking that radio button
```

Answer (score 0):

In the server side you should get the radio button click event and you must rebind the dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Pamblam!!!
You saved my life!!!
Sorry I can't comment yet but really want to thank my life saviour~!!!

Here is my working codes:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){$(".time-section").addClass("hidden");

    $("input[type='radio'][name='time-select']").change(function () {
            var timeSelected = $("input[type='radio'][name='time-select']:checked").val();
            $(".time-section").removeClass("hidden");

        if (timeSelected == "Lunch") var timeOpts = [
                {name:"Lunch: 12:00pm",val:"Lunch: 12:00pm"},
                {name:"Lunch: 12:30pm",val:"Lunch: 12:30pm"},
                {name:"Lunch: 1:00pm",val:"Lunch: 1:00pm"},
                {name:"Lunch: 1:30pm",val:"Lunch: 1:30pm"}
            ]

        else if (timeSelected == "Dinner") var timeOpts = [
                {name:"Dinner: 6:30pm - 8:30pm",val:"Dinner: 6:30pm - 8:30pm"},
                {name:"Dinner: 8:30pm - 10:30pm",val:"Dinner: 8:30pm - 10:30pm"}
            ]

        $("#Times").empty();

        $.each(timeOpts, function(k,v){

            $("#Times").append("<option value='"+v.val+"'>"+v.name+"</option>");

        }); 

    });


});
```

Here I modified a bit the codes so after I've selected "Lunch" or "Dinner" then only the dropdown menu of timeslot appear.

Hope this is helpful for someone some day. :)